# Question about Ratio test

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if 
>   $
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}}
> $
>   converges
>   $
> \left ( a_{n}> 0 \right )
> $
>   then 
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1+\sin a_{n}}{2} \right )^n
> $$
>   converges.

I have a feeling that it is right, but I have no idea how to write exact proof to it :( any hint would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty } \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1+\sin a_n}{2}\right|^n } =\lim_{n\to\infty } \left|\frac{1+\sin a_n}{2}\right|=\frac{1}{2} <1$$  hence the series converges.

Comment: Oh, I forgot there was root test. Things can be done more neatly this way than using the comparison test. thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

show that the terms in your sequence are, from some point smaller than something bigger than $1/2$, like $2/3$ for example and then use the comparison criterion with a geometric series. do you think you can prove my first assertion using the convergence of $\sum a_n$?

hint: necessary condition

Comment: well, it's basically what @David Mitra said in his comment

Comment: so how about starting like this? because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}$ converges to 0, there is a finite number N that when  n>N, $\frac{sina_{n}+1}{2}<1$.

Comment: @user154670 That won't quite do. You want ${\sin a_n+1\over 2}<r<1$ for some fixed $r$ (so that $\sum r^n$ converges).